# React: how to initiate a variable with API call response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a table that uses an api to access data from a database.

```
import { COLUMNS } from './ActivityColumns.js'
import { getTable } from "./ApiCall.js"

export const SortingTable = () => {

    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    const [aaa, setData] = useState([])

    const getData = () => {
        getTable('activity').then(result => {
            console.log('returning result')
            return result;
        })
    }

    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: COLUMNS,
        data: getData()
    },
    useSortBy)
}
```

The result in `getData()` is the expected one, an array of Object dicts `[ {..}, {..}, ..., {..}]`. The problem is that when `tableInstance` tries to set the `data` as the result of `getData()`, I get the following error: `useTable.js:591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')`
The exact line that causes the error is from `useTable.js`:

```
  data.forEach((originalRow, rowIndex) =>
    accessRow(originalRow, rowIndex, 0, undefined, rows)
  )
```

Before using an API I used a json file that has the same structure as the API's response: `[{..}, {..}, {..}]`. This one worked.

What goes wrong when trying to initiate with an API and how can I fix this error?

Edit 1: I tried to declare `getData` inside the hook

```
export const SortingTable = () => {

    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    
    const getData = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
     
       const getData = () => {
         getTable('activity').then(result => {
           console.log('returning result')
           console.log(result)
           setData(result);
         })
       }
     
       getData();
     
       return data;
    }
    
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: COLUMNS,
        data: getData
    },
    useSortBy)
    
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, footerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = tableInstance
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` function does not have a return. This means calling `getData()` would give you `undefined`.

Is `useTable` OK to work with an asynchronous function?
If so, just return something from `getData`.

If it expects its synchronous data you might need to put the results of `getData` into state so that it gets populated once available which in turn causes a rerender of your component and calling `useTable` again.

```
import { COLUMNS } from './ActivityColumns.js'
import { getTable } from "./ApiCall.js"

export const SortingTable = () => {

    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    const [aaa, setData] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
            getData(); // <-----
    }, []);
    
    const getData = () => {
        getTable('activity').then(result => {
            setData(result); // <-----
        })
    }
    
    const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns: COLUMNS,
        data: aaa // <-----
    },
    useSortBy)
}
```

The reason why your JSON was loaded without issue and your fetching is problematic is probably because you just imported/required the JSON which is synchronous while `getTable` obviously returns a thenable/Promise.

Comment: it has a `return result` statement. How can it give an undefined?

Comment: Your getData() has no return statement. The callback of a Promise inside it has a `return result`. But that result is not returned out of getData.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I am quite new to React. Could you please send me a guide where I can see how this solution could be implemented?

Comment: You first need to understand how promises work and what comes after what.

Comment: I've updated my answer above to give you an idea of what you need if useTable does not expect a Promise in data.

Comment: This version almost works, but `getData` is not used. I also added `useEffect(() =>{ getData() })`. Now I see indeed the data from the database, but also now the API is being called continuosly, as a loop is created: useEffect -> get data from api and set it -> state is changed -> reload -> repeat. Is there any way of avoiding this loop besides initiating the data with `null`, then in `useEffect` add a clause `if data is null: getData()`?

Comment: If you don't want getData to be called only once, your useEffect should have [] dependency array - effectively calling it only on mount. Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

`getData` doesn't return anything. So effectively you're passing `useTable` an object `{columns: COLUMNS, data: undefined}`.

One way to fix this is to declare `getData` inside your hook, and use state to save the result of the API call:

```js
const useTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = () => {
    getTable('activity').then(result => {
      console.log('returning result')
      setData(result);
    })
  }

  getData();

  // do whatever you want to do here with COLUMNS

  return data;
}
```

Comment: i tried to use your solution and now I get `React Hook "useState" is called in function "getData" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function`. I pasted the code in the post, under `Edit 1`. Did I write the code correctly? I am new to React

Comment: You should use the code I suggested in your useTable hook. I'm assuming that's a custom hook you wrote yourself (it's unclear if it is or not from your code). However, if you're importing useTable from some library, you can use Valery's latest suggestion and it should work.